# Creating a CGRect around a UITextView - Wrong Height

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am creating a dynamic column to the left of a UITextview that matches the height of each paragraph. For some reason I have a problem getting the correct height of the ranges. I am using:

```
let test = textView.firstRect(for: models.first!.range)
```

It’s a single line behind as you keep typing. Examples:

2 Lines
[image]

3 Lines
[image]

Any ideas what’s wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example where the docs could use a little help...

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614570-firstrect:

> **Return Value**
>
> The first rectangle in a range of text. You might use this rectangle to draw a correction rectangle. The “first” in the name refers the rectangle enclosing the first line when the range encompasses multiple lines of text.

Which is not, in fact, exactly right.

For example, if you select the text:

[image]

You don't have **a rectangle**. Using Debug View Hierarchy:

[image]

It's clear that you have **two** rectangles.

So, `func firstRect(for range: UITextRange) -> CGRect` actually returns the ***first rectangle*** from the ***set of rectangles*** needed to contain the range.

To get the actual height of the range of text (the paragraph, for example), you'll need to use:

```
let rects = selectionRects(for: textRange)
```

and then loop through the returned array of `UITextSelectionRect` objects.

---

**Edit:**

There are various different approaches to accomplish this, but here is a quick simple example of looping through selection rects and summing their heights:

```
//
//  ParagraphMarkerViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 6/17/19.
//

import UIKit

extension UITextView {

    func boundingFrame(ofTextRange range: Range<String.Index>?) -> CGRect? {

        guard let range = range else { return nil }
        let length = range.upperBound.encodedOffset-range.lowerBound.encodedOffset
        guard
            let start = position(from: beginningOfDocument, offset: range.lowerBound.encodedOffset),
            let end = position(from: start, offset: length),
            let txtRange = textRange(from: start, to: end)
            else { return nil }

        // we now have a UITextRange, so get the selection rects for that range
        let rects = selectionRects(for: txtRange)

        // init our return rect
        var returnRect = CGRect.zero

        // for each selection rectangle
        for thisSelRect in rects {

            // if it's the first one, just set the return rect
            if thisSelRect == rects.first {
                returnRect = thisSelRect.rect
            } else {
                // ignore selection rects with a width of Zero
                if thisSelRect.rect.size.width > 0 {
                    // we only care about the top (the minimum origin.y) and the
                    // sum of the heights
                    returnRect.origin.y = min(returnRect.origin.y, thisSelRect.rect.origin.y)
                    returnRect.size.height += thisSelRect.rect.size.height
                }
            }

        }
        return returnRect
    }

}

class ParagraphMarkerViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    var theTextView: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
        return v
    }()

    var paragraphMarkers: [UIView] = [UIView]()

    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .red,
        .green,
        .blue,
        .cyan,
        .orange,
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(theTextView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            theTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            theTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -60.0),
            theTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            theTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            ])

        theTextView.delegate = self

        // start with some example text
        theTextView.text = "This is a single line." +
        "\n\n" +
        "After two embedded newline chars, this text will wrap." +
        "\n\n" +
        "Here is another paragraph. It should be enough text to wrap to multiple lines in this textView. As you enter new text, the paragraph marks should adjust accordingly."

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // update markers on viewDidAppear
        updateParagraphMarkers()
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // update markers when text view is edited
        updateParagraphMarkers()
    }

    @objc func updateParagraphMarkers() -> Void {

        // clear previous paragraph marker views
        paragraphMarkers.forEach {
            $0.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        // reset paraMarkers array
        paragraphMarkers.removeAll()

        // probably not needed, but this will make sure the the text container has updated
        theTextView.layoutManager.ensureLayout(for: theTextView.textContainer)

        // make sure we have some text
        guard let str = theTextView.text else { return }

        // get the full range
        let textRange = str.startIndex..<str.endIndex

        // we want to enumerate by paragraphs
        let opts:NSString.EnumerationOptions = .byParagraphs

        var i = 0

        str.enumerateSubstrings(in: textRange, options: opts) {
            (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, _) in

            // get the bounding rect for the sub-rects in each paragraph
            if let boundRect = self.theTextView.boundingFrame(ofTextRange: enclosingRange) {

                // create a UIView
                let v = UIView()

                // give it a background color from our array of colors
                v.backgroundColor = self.colors[i % self.colors.count]

                // init the frame
                v.frame = boundRect

                // needs to be offset from the top of the text view
                v.frame.origin.y += self.theTextView.frame.origin.y

                // position it 48-pts to the left of the text view
                v.frame.origin.x = self.theTextView.frame.origin.x - 48

                // give it a width of 40-pts
                v.frame.size.width = 40

                // add it to the view
                self.view.addSubview(v)

                // save a reference to this UIView in our array of markers
                self.paragraphMarkers.append(v)

                i += 1

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Okay! How should I loop through the returned array and union them?

Comment: @cookie.mink - there are various ways to accomplish what you're trying to do... See the edits to my answer for a simple example that should get you on your way.

Comment: Woah, this is amazing. 2 quick questions: 1. What is the reason I would delete everything in the array, I possibly could have 100’s of paragraphs could this be a problem or is the text parsing pretty quick? 2. I am going to have buttons in every ‘paragraph’ view, knowing everything above can you give me some quick advice on how I should go about linking the paragraphs to the side view components. Would I need them to have id’s that link to each paragraph? So if the paragraph were deleted the view/button would know which to delete?

Comment: @cookie.mink - if you're possibly going to have *"100’s of paragraphs"* you have a ***lot*** more work to do. You'd likely have only a few paragraphs visible at any time, so parsing all of the non-visible text would be very inefficient. You'd need to develop logic to cache the non-visible text... Adding and manipulating 100s of subviews is probably not feasible, so you might want to create your own control and draw the rects yourself... *Possibly* put them in a table view and sync the scrolling... but that is all far beyond the scope of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Using below code you'll get the correct content size of the text view.

```
let newSize = self.textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: self.textView.frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        print("\(newSize.height)")
```

Change the height of the dynamic column according to this height. If you want to change the column height while user is typing then do this in `UITextViewDelegate` method `textViewDidChange`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: He is asking for `height of the each paragraph` not the height of whole `textView`.

Comment: @TheTiger Correct! I need to get the height of each paragraph, so need to use `firstRect` or something similar!